# Can't use some commands in repeated theorem name when using apxproof

Tags: theorems, proof-package

For some reason I can't use some commands, such as `\def` in the name of a theorem when using `apxproof`'s repeated theorems. And I can't understand why. It does not seem to be related to the fact that the theorem is repeated or not, since adding the `[appendix=strip]` option to the `apxproof` package does not fix the problem.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\newtheoremrep{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nicecommand}{(Nice command)}
%\newcommand{\notnicecommand}{a\\b}
\newcommand{\notnicecommand}{\def\mything{a}}

% thmrep with any some commands in the name works
\begin{thmrep}[Name A\nicecommand]
    Text A
\end{thmrep}

% thm with any command in the name works
\begin{thm}[Name B\notnicecommand]
    Text B
\end{thm}

% thm with any command in the name works, even when pushed to the appendix
\begin{toappendix}
    \begin{thm}[Name C\notnicecommand]
        Text C
    \end{thm}
\end{toappendix}

% thm rep with a not nice command in the name does not work
\begin{thmrep}[Name D\notnicecommand]
    Text D
\end{thmrep}% Undefined control sequence. \end{thmrep}

\end{document}
```

My real use case is that I want to use a macro that uses this one in the name of a theorem:

```
\newcommand{\latexiteeq}[4]{%
  \def\tmpa{#1}%
  \def\tmpb{#2}%
  \ifx\tmpa\tmpb%
    #3
  \else%
    #4
  \fi%
}
```

Edit: I managed to rewrite `\latexiteeq` in a way that avoids using `\def` but I still have the same problem because some other part of the macro I use uses `\def`.

Comment: Most likely `thmrep` tries to expand `\notnicecommand`, which isn't possible, because it has a `\def` inside.

Comment: Try `\ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}\relax#3\else#4\fi` instead of `\def\tmpa{#1}..\ifx...\fi` inside that macro. `\pdfstrcmp` works for pdftex and pdflatex only, however, but is expandable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. This does remove the problems caused by `\latexiteeq`. But apparently, I have other macros that use `\def` or some other "not nice" commands. And those are in complicated packages that I'd rather not mess with.

Comment: Yes, but the other macros are not in your posted example, are they?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The commented `\notnicecommand` makes it fail too. And I just found a new one: `\scalebox{0.5}{a}`.

Comment: Looks like you have a very strange setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\robustify` from `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\usepackage{etoolbox}         %  <----------------- added this package
\newtheoremrep{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nicecommand}{(Nice command)}
%\newcommand{\notnicecommand}{a\\b}
\newcommand{\notnicecommand}{\def\mything{a}}
\robustify{\notnicecommand}  % <----------------- added this line

\begin{thmrep}[Name A\nicecommand]
    Text A
\end{thmrep}

\begin{thm}[Name B\notnicecommand]
    Text B
\end{thm}

\begin{toappendix}
    \begin{thm}[Name C\notnicecommand]
        Text C
    \end{thm}
\end{toappendix}

\begin{thmrep}[Name D\notnicecommand]
    Text D
\end{thmrep}

\end{document}
```